# Show element html with Angular with ngTemplate

Tags: angular

I get from my server a Object in a JSON. I have multiples vars.

I want check 1 var, if I have this var a null, I wan't show "a>

```
<div *ngIf="{{param.exist}} !== null #myData" ></div>
<ng-template #myData>
    <a href="{{param.link}}">
        <clr-icon shape="info-standard"></clr-icon>Reporting
    </a>
</ng-template>
```

The problem is that this doesnt run..

Edit:

I have show the label a href...> but only if I get data from my json:

Example Json:

```
{
 "exist":null,
 "link": null
},
{
 "exist":"units",
 "link": "http:\\www.myUnits..."
}
```

I tried with ng-Template for nothing, I aslo tried with:

```
<ng-template *ngIf="enableValidation(param.exist)">
    <a href="{{param.link}}">
        <clr-icon shape="info-standard"></clr-icon> Acceder
    </a>
</ng-template>

enableValidation(exist: any) {
    if (exist === null) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But never shows nothing. thanks.

Comment: Sorry but it's not very clear what you intend to achieve here.  Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @sid read my edit,pls

Comment: no need to use #  in the if else expression, you are using wrong syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this approach

```
<div *ngIf="checkNull()" >
                                <a href="{{param.link}}">
                                    <clr-icon shape="info-standard"></clr-icon>   Reporting
                                </a>
   </div>
```

and in your **.ts** file

```
list = [{
 "exist":null,
 "link": null
},
{
 "exist":"units",
 "link": "http:\\www.myUnits..."
}];

checkNull() {
    return this.list.every(obj => !obj.exist);
  }
```

this will show the anchor tag only when `exist` in every object is not null or undefined or not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way , as you can see you have used wrong syntax : https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else

```
<div  *ngIf="param && param.exist;else myData;">
   //when condition true display 
</div>

<ng-template #myData>
   <a href="{{param.link}}">
      <clr-icon shape="info-standard"></clr-icon>   Reporting
   </a>
</ng-template>
```